# MS ACCESS 2013 Displaying Data Rows for users to be able to click and open a new form

Tags: forms, vba, listview, ms-access

I'm just starting to get into Access due to my job and am tasked with creating a form that displays Data for the individual users on load.  Basically what it needs to do is to get data from 3 tables, join them together, and then display the found rows that match that person's accounts they are responsible for managing.

I have this working via a single table Query using a listbox and a datasheet view, however, being a web developer by trade, I would like functionality that displays items similar to what a Unordered List(UL) would display and with functionality that allows the user to click on the company name(which acts as a hyperlink) to then update the information in a new form that I have built, by loading that data into the form, and allowing them to update the fields that I have designated as changeable.

Is this possible in Access via a form or would this be too difficult to implement?  I'm decent with VBA, still learning what a lot of the things do, but as far as the logic and things like that to make something happen, I can do that no problem.  These rows all have a unique ID so I would be able to either keep them in a collection to populate the form data or I can simply requery the data using the ID number for loading the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listbox performs like a combobox in datasheet view. Did you mean you have a combobox?

Actually very simple to accomplish, and various methods available. I assume you have a form bound to your Query with a combobox that lists companies. Controls have events. Use the Click event of the Company control. I use only VBA (not macros but macro could do this). Select [Event Procedure] in the event property. Click the ellipses (...) to open VBA Code Editor, type code into the procedure:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "CompanyInfo", , , "ID=" & Me.tbxCompany`

Keep in mind, controls used for the purpose of entering/selecting filter criteria should be UNBOUND, otherwise you would change data in record. However, using the Click event of a BOUND combobox (as long as you click on the box, not the dropdown) or textbox will not change existing data, not so for a listbox.

Comment: No, actually what we have is 3 sharepoint lists that are linked to the DB, representing the 3 tables that I need to query(although each user is USUALLY only in one of the tables).  I have a form that loads and then I use Environ("username") to get their username, and then use that to search the tables for the records matching them, which are then displayed in a ListBox/SubForm, other control at the bottom of the form on load...however, I don't want them looking like a datasheet, but rather like how lists are displayed in HTML

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with SharePoint. So, will the suggested VBA code be usable?

Comment: I think I actually got it working by taking your advice on the ID_click() event and then setting the Forms("Form1").label.captions to the appropriate values and then setting Focus to Form1...  SharePoint simply creates a linked table in Access, so you just get the data like you would any other table